# jQuery - Use window scrollbar to scroll content inside a DIV

Tags: jquery, scrollbar

Is it possible to use window scrollers to scroll a big DIV content? instead of its own div scroller?

Comment: why would you want to do that?

Comment: I want to make it work like an iframe on the page. Basically I have a left thumbnail vertical strip that has position FIXED on left. and clicking it opens up big image on right. but sometimes image is super big. so i want to scroll image but want to use main window scroller instead of another set of scroller inside window.

Answer (score 2):

**Something like**

- Make the body fixed position
- Add event listeners to body scroll
- Apply the body scroll to the desired container

Answer (score 2):

### Use Windows scrollbar as separate element

It appears to be very simple to use de standard browser scrollbar as a seperate
scrollbar for any purpose.
You just need 3 `<div>` with some CSS-parameters:

- `container-div`:
  to reposition the `scrollbox-div` a little bit to the left (otherwise the content-div
  stays visible).
- `scrollbox-div`:
  The `scrollbox-div` gets the scrollbar, because it contains the `contents-div`, which
  is larger then the `scrollbox-div`. The `scrollbox-div` is relative-repositioned to
  the left (-24px), so the `contents-div` is not visible in the `container-div`.
  The `contents-div` can not be made much smaller then about `33 px`, otherwise the scrollbar disappears in IE.
- the `contents-div`:
  The `contents-div` is larger then the `srollbox-div` to force a scrollbar.
  It contains NOTHING, so it will be invisible

By changing the `container+scrollbox-height` and the `content-height` you can
change the scrollbar handle size.
Just experiment by changing the parameters.

With some jquery you can get/set the `scrolltop-value`. So with this parameter and some
jquery you can select any part of data you want to display.

**HTML:**

```
<body>
<div id="container" >  
   <div id="scrollbox" >  
        <div id="content" >
        </div>  
   </div>  
</div>  
<p>scrolltop= <span id="scrolltop" ></span></p>
</body>
```

**CSS:**

```
#container{   
    width: 16px;   
    height: 500px;
    overflow: hidden;
 }   
#scrollbox{   
    width: 40px;   
    height: 500px; 
    position:relative;
    left: -24px;  
    overflow: auto;
}   
#content{   
    height: 50000px;   
}
```

**JQUERY:**

```
$('document').ready(function(){
  $("#scrollbox").scroll( 
    function () {
      var scrolltop=$('#scrollbox').scrollTop();
      $('#scrolltop').text(scrolltop);
    }
  );  
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the scrollbar only affects the overall page, and not a specific element, no.. at least not without replacing the scrollbar entirely (strongly discouraged).