# Scrolling all page contents instead of div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jsp

Hi I have a MasterPage that contains a #MasterDiv where the banner+navbar are. I include this page in all my other pages that have a layout like this.

```
     <body>
       <jsp:include page="../Master.jsp"></jsp:include>
        <div class="Contents">
             Textboxes, buttons, etc... go here
        </div>
    </body>
```

I have a JQuery function to "fixate" the #MasterDiv to the top of the page when scrolling like so.

```
    $window.scroll(function() {
        var y = $window.scrollTop() - MasterDivOffset.top + topPadding;
        if($window.scrollTop() > MasterDivOffset.top){
          $masterDiv.stop().animate()({marginTop : y});
        } else {
          $masterDiv.stop().animate()({marginTop : 8, marginLeft : 8});
        }
    });
```

But this moves all of the page contents instead of sticking the div to the op!
I've tried position:fixed on the div but that causes the div where the page contents (page specific fields, buttons, etc...) are to "spring up" instead of staying in the same position.

How can I stick that specific div to the top while scrolling down the rest of the page?

Comment: add fix height to that specific div and add `overflow:auto` that will scroll div instead a whole page

Comment: i think this can help you to solve your problem

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4271750/jquery-use-window-scrollbar-to-scroll-content-inside-a-div

Comment: @Justcode that's not what I meant. I want to use the browser scroll bar to scroll the page while fixing the navbar to the top.
I have edited my topic in order to clarify the question. tHANKS

Comment: @DevendraSoni thanks. It worked but not the way that it should. But its given me something to go by.

Comment: always welcome :) if it was helpful to you then you can vote it :d

Comment: One vote comin' up :)